# Getting an " Unhandled promise rejection" error when making transaction from account1 to a contract

Tags: contract-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nodejs

I keep getting a Promise Rejection error whenever I make a transaction from account 1 to a contract. The contract is used to send ether to account 2 when it receives ether from account 1. For security purposes, I am not displaying my private keys.

Here's my Web3.js code:-

```
const Tx = require("ethereumjs-tx").Transaction
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/3665d10cb9c34785809c45aae7a9e0c4"))

const account1 = '0x29C369b42F7444eeF05B64574c4145Da83A9F422' // Your account address 1
const account2 = '0x9F328cE10312Cd5b67aCBeD3b23051Da60f66D67' // Your account address 2

const privateKey1 = Buffer.from('privateKey1'.substr(2), 'hex')
const privateKey2 = Buffer.from('privateKey2'.substr(2), 'hex')

// Read the deployed contract - get the addresss from Etherscan
const contractAddress = '0xdFE373a3043c1602C35982d3deB262cA3700ef74'
const contractABI= [{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_initialSupply","type":"uint256"}],"name":"DappToken2","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"standard","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"_to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress)

// Transfer some tokens
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, function(err, txCount){ 

  const txObject = {
    nonce:    web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(800000), // Raise the gas limit to a much higher amount
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
    to: contractAddress,
    data: contract.methods.transfer(account2, 1000).encodeABI()
  }

  const tx = new Tx(txObject, {'chain':'ropsten'})
  tx.sign(privateKey1)

  const serializedTx = tx.serialize()
  var raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, function(err, txHash){
    if(err){
        console.log('err:',err)
    }
    else{
        console.log('txHash:',txHash)
    }
    // Use this txHash to find the contract on Etherscan!
  })
})
```

The error is as follows:-

```
at Object.TransactionError (/mnt/d/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:93:21)
    at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (/mnt/d/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:105:21)
    at /mnt/d/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:482:48
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:228) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 14)
(node:228) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I tried using an async function but that didn't work. All the solutions mentioned on Ethereum Stack Exchange regarding Promise rejection don't work either.

**[Edit]** Here's the solidity code for the ERC-20 token contract:-

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract DappToken {
    string  public name = "DApp Token";
    string  public symbol = "DAPP";
    string  public standard = "DApp Token v1.0";
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    event Transfer(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
    );

    event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
    );

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    function DappToken2 (uint256 _initialSupply) public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;

        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);

        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: From the error message the contract is failing, likely a require or assert is the culprit.

Comment: @Ismael Thank you for your comment. I am not using an assert or require statement in the program.

Comment: The contract is executing a revert, it may not be code you have explicitly written but it is there, perhaps an array access out of bound, using unallocated memory, invalid inputs, etc. It can be anything.

Comment: @Ismael What do you recommend I should do? Leave the code as is or continue finding a solution. I have tried all the solutions mentioned on the internet and nothing works. I don't know how to program in solidity, therefore, I can't look for issues in the contract itself.

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be in the javascript snippet. You can add the solidity code here. Is it an ERC-20 token? Does account1 has enough tokens?

Comment: @Ismael Yes it's an ERC-20 token. I am actually using fake ether from the Ropsten test network. Maybe that's the issue. I transferred 1 Ether from meta Mask to account 1, so I don't think there are issues with that otherwise the code would display an error saying "insufficient tokens for gas Price." Also, I added the solidity code. Thank you for your help this far.

Comment: One issue with the solidity code is that it is not being initialized properly. You have a function named `DappToken2` that appears to be the constructor but it is not since the contract is called `DappToken`. Since solc 0.5 it is recommended to use `constructor` instead to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: @Ismael Thanks! That solved the problem. Sorry, I replied to you late because I was getting other problems with the code, but I managed to solve it.